# how many times does the user want to play a game c language

Tags: c

I am learning how to write a game I have been given the following rules for the game.

- Rule 1: Players must define a minimum number to stop the turn this has to be greater than 10
- Rule 2: all point from round are added to the total
- Rule 3: If the dice lands on 1 then all points for that round are forfeited
- Rule 4: First player to get to 101 points WINS!

I am trying to get the number of games to be inputted in after the user enters how many players there are.

My problem is it ask the user every time I enter the players names depending on how many players I have inputted

***Example***

> How many Players: 3
>
> How many games: 15
>
> Enter Players name: John
>
> How many games: 15 (I input this number again) I dont need this line here
>
> Enter Players name: Mary
>
> How many games: 15 (I input this number again) I dont need this line here
>
> Enter Players name: Barry
>
> How many games: 15 (I input this number again) I dont need this line here

This is my code for the problem:

```
//user inputs value of player_num, here, as you have now//

printf_s("Please type in the number of players: ");
scanf_s("%d", &player_num, sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < player_num; i++) {
    //user inputs value of num_game, here, as you have now//
    printf_s("Please type in the number of games: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num_games, sizeof(int));
    num_games = (j = 1, num_games);

    printf_s("Enter the player's first name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", names[i], 25);  
    getchar();               
}
printf_s("\n");
for (i = 0; i < player_num; i++)
    printf_s("\n%s", names[i]);
```

Comment: Structure your code so that it matches your requirements..

Comment: You could improve your [mcve] but it's globally a good question.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it keeps asking you to "input the number of games" again and again is because you've put the printf and scanf statement in the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < player_num; i++) {
printf_s("Please type in the number of games: ");//this
scanf_s("%d", &num_games, sizeof(int));//this
num_games = (j = 1, num_games); //including this

printf_s("Enter the player's first name: ");// also this
scanf_s("%s", names[i], 25);  // and this
getchar();
}
```

Due to this each time the loop is executed, it asks you to enter the value.

instead if you want it to ask you once, you must put it outside the loop if you want the statements to be executed once only.

You can do this if you want to :

> get the number of games to be inputted in after the user enters how
>   many players there are.

```
printf_s("Please type in the number of players: ");
scanf_s("%d", &player_num, sizeof(int));
printf_s("Please type in the number of games: ");
scanf_s("%d", &num_games, sizeof(int));
num_games = (j = 1, num_games);
```

and it is

> asking the user every time you enter the players names depending on how
>   many players you have inputted
>   because you've entered those lines "inside the loop";

Answer (score 0):

your loop has 2 `scanf`, while you need only one. Put this

`printf_s("Please type in the number of games: ");
scanf_s("%d", &num_games, sizeof(int));
num_games = (j = 1, num_games);`

in front of your loop, instead of inside it.

```
for (i = 0; i < player_num; i++) {

  //user inputs value of num_game, here, as you have now//
  printf_s("Please type in the number of games: ");  // no need for this in the loop
  scanf_s("%d", &num_games, sizeof(int));            // no need for this in the loop   
  num_games = (j = 1, num_games);                    // no need for this in the loop


  printf_s("Enter the player's first name: ");
  scanf_s("%s", names[i], 25);  
  getchar();               
}
```

Comment: i took the statement out of the loop. now it crashes but i decided i needed to change the name of that particular loop and took advantage of that bug and turned it into one of the conditions within the game whic it ask the user the minimum number to stop their turn. it doesnt actually solve my problem of asking the questions in the following order

Comment: 1. ask how many players.( has to be more than 1 player)

2. How Many games (only asked once)

3. Users name (asked as many times as number 1 was entered)

4. Minimum number stop (asked as many times as number 1 was entered but number entered here must be greater than 10)

Comment: @ElijahCeeney you didn't show a MCVE. I could only point out what was the problem in the code you showed...

Comment: its ok i solved the issue thank you. i have no idea what MCVE is. i am pretty knew to all of this. the pointing out of the issue helped me solve the problem